# Unit test for Exception secario using Mock

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, nunit, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a API, where the Return type is `IActionResult`. Pseudo Code as below

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Getdata()
{
   var result = await _report.Getall(DateTime.UtcNow);
}
```

I am trying to write Unit test for this as below.

```cs
[Test]
public async Task Error_code()
{
    _report.Setup(r => r.Getall(It.IsAny<DateTime>())).ThrowsAsync(new Exception("Error Message"));
    var result = await _reportCnt.Getdata(); //_reportCnt is object of the Controller
    Assert.AreEqual("Error Message",reuslt);
}
```

*But the issue i am facing is, Once the Error is thrown from the API, its not going to Assert, It's failing the Unit test with Error* `Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown`.

I have tried these 3 ways

```cs
var result = await _reportCnt.Getdata() as ObjectResult;
var result = await _reportCnt.Getdata() as ActionResult;
var result = await _reportCnt.Getdata() as ExceptionResult;
```

but not working, throwing the same issue.

Anything i am missing here or any suggestion?

Comment: Try annotating your test method with [ExpectedException(typeof(Exception))] attribute. Right below the [Test] attribute.

Comment: I am using NUnit, but ExpectedException is there in MsTest. But still in NUnit we have Assert.throwsAsync(). But tried the same it throws different issue. Still can you give a Code refrence Or Some Psuedo Code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you have setup your mock to throw an exception you can expect that by invoking the method under test like this:

```
[Test]
public void Test1()
{
    _report.Setup(r => r.Getall(It.IsAny<DateTime>())).ThrowsAsync(new Exception("Error Message"));

    var exceptionThrown = Assert.ThrowsAsync<Exception>(async () => await _reportCnt.Getdata());

    Assert.AreEqual("Error Message", exceptionThrown.Message);
}
```

Comment: The `ThrowsAsync` returns the thrown exception, which could be examined. So, the exception's Message could be verified as well (as it was the intent of the OP)

Comment: You are perfectly right Peter, I missed it. I updated my answer, thank you.

Comment: One more tiny thing. Your test is synchronous, so `public void Test1()` would be sufficient. Even though `ThrowsAsync` accepts an async delegate it is [executed synchronously](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/assertions/classic-assertions/Assert.ThrowsAsync.html).

Answer (score -1):

This is an example testing the default `WeatherForecastController` returning `ActionResult` instead of `IActionResult`. You can read about the benefits here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-5.0#actionresultt-type

```
[Authorize]
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]

public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

    private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

    public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>> Get()
    {
        var rng = new Random();
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
        .ToArray();
    }
}
```

Test using `xUnit` but you should be abele to convert to `NUnit`.

```
[Fact]
public void DummyTest()
{
    var logger = Mock.Of<ILogger<WeatherForecastController>>();
    var controller = new WeatherForecastController(logger);

    var result = controller.Get().Value.First();

    Assert.True(result.Date.Date == DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).Date, "Date is current date");

    Assert.Throws<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(() => controller.Get().Value.ToList()[5]);
}
```

Comment: In my previous Project i have already Mocked ILogger & yes its Perfect. But in my current context Ilogger am not using & neither i have try {} catch {}, as i am handling in ExceptionFilter.

Comment: How does this answer the OP's question?

Comment: @PeterCsala It shows an `ASP.NET Web API` unit test and how to test a `Controller` properly. I agree a better answer would include an `async await` call and `NUnit` but unfortunately I did not have time for that when writing the answer and it was too much code for a comment.

Comment: According to my understanding the OP's question is about how to verify a method call which throws an exception. Your provided sample does not operate with exceptions.

Comment: @PeterCsala Very true, thanks for pointing that out. Updated with verifying a method call that throws an exception.